# STL memory conflicts with std memory

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm rewriting some legacy code and would like to use both STL AND smart pointers. However, memory is defined in STL, so if I include memory then it's some STL code and smart pointers are unavailable.

Whats a workaround? Rename the STL file and any references to it? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @n.m.: it's legacy code - perhaps it is using the SGI STL, or STLport or whatever, as an alternative to the Standard Library.  @slacker: I suggest you use `boost` for smart pointers - that avoids file name and namespace conflicts.

Comment: Hm, does your legacy code actually reference STL? As in `#include <stl/vector.h>`?

Comment: Ah, boost is a great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply going to use boost to circumvent the conflicts. Thanks, Tony D!